# C++: What is the difference between `const T &` and `T &&` in the context of parameters of a function?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

Say we have a function that accepts a parameter, and this parameter will only be used for reading. Now we don't want to copy the passed in parameter, rather we just want to move it (for efficiency reasons).

Is there any difference between passing it as a `const T &` and a `T &&`? and which should be used.

Here's an example

---

```cpp
void    printRange(const int & start, const int & stop)
{
    for ( int i = start; i < stop; ++i)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

/*                      VS                              */

void    printRange(int && start, int && stop)
{
    for ( int i = start; i < stop; ++i)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a difference? What is it? and what is the better choice?

---

Here taking the integers by value would be the way to go:

"Because when you take them by value, they are local variables.
Reference can refer to global mutable variable, so technically, start and end can change inside any function call. Because of that, the compiler cannot elide the loads and must dereference the variable everytime.
Take this for example: [godbolt disection of code](https://godbolt.org/z/DbR1ys).

As you can see, a bit after the label `.L3` (it's the loop) you can see `cmp DWORD PTR [rbp+0]`, `ebx`. That's a pointer dereference load. In the value version, both int simply sits in registers.

Also, when passing a reference around, you acutally are passing a pointer. That pointer is 8 bytes. So you are passing 16 bytes worth of parameter. Simply ints on the other hand are 4 bytes. Passing a int around by value, even with optimisation off is technically lighter.

Read this, that's also a [good explanation by a university professor](http://lemire.me/blog/2019/09/05/)…
And... there is also aliasing. If the ints are by reference, they can both alias each other, so it's also harder for the optimizer
I think that's all. Maybe there is other factor I don't know."

-@GuillaumeRacicot

Comment: Only one of these can be moved, but `printRange` doesn't take ownership of anything so move semantics doesn't apply in the first place.

Comment: I'm curious what the context of this question is. It looks like something you would find on a quiz or a written exam.

Comment: It wont compile. You can't increment `start` in the const version.

Comment: -__- my bad fixed it @GuillaumeRacicot

Comment: @AymenTM see? The const is better. It would have compiled with the non const version and do the wrong thing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, there is no special context actually. Just a question :/

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, but hey, with `const T &`, if the parameter is an Rvalue, is it moved into the function? or copied?

Comment: Both are reference, and both are (close) equivalent. No copy. The dupe explain is quite well in fact. But the best would be to take the ints by value.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot why would the best "be to take the ints by value"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199385/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-aymentm).

Answer (score 0):

Use the first one.

Second can only take "temporaries".